# Is it possible to obtain specific message offset in Spark+KafkaRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm trying to read from Kafka by using a KafkaRDD in order to get messages and metadata. 
The method that I'm using is the follow:

```
val messageHandler = (mmd: MessageAndMetadata[String,Array[Byte]]) => {
  (mmd.message(), mmd.offset)
}

   val messagesAndMetadata = KafkaUtils.createRDD[String, Array[Byte], StringDecoder, DefaultDecoder, Tuple2[String,Long]]
    (sc.asInstanceOf[SparkContext], KafkaParams, offsetRangeTrete, leaderForPartitionsMap, messageHandler)
```

but the compiler is showing an error:

```
ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method createRDD in object KafkaUtils of type 
(jsc: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext, keyClass: Class[String], valueClass: Class[String], keyDecoderClass: Class[kafka.serializer.StringDecoder], valueDecoderClass: Class[kafka.serializer.StringDecoder], recordClass: Class[String], kafkaParams: java.util.Map[String,String], offsetRanges: Array[org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.OffsetRange], leaders: java.util.Map[kafka.common.TopicAndPartition,org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.Broker], messageHandler: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function[kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata[String,String],String])org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[String]
and  method createRDD in object KafkaUtils of type (sc: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, kafkaParams: Map[String,String], offsetRanges: Array[org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.OffsetRange], leaders: Map[kafka.common.TopicAndPartition,org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.Broker], messageHandler: kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata[String,String] => String)(implicit evidence$9: scala.reflect.ClassTag[String], implicit evidence$10: scala.reflect.ClassTag[String], implicit evidence$11: scala.reflect.ClassTag[kafka.serializer.StringDecoder], implicit evidence$12: scala.reflect.ClassTag[kafka.serializer.StringDecoder], implicit evidence$13: scala.reflect.ClassTag[String])org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
match expected type ?
[ERROR]     val treteMetadata = org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils.createRDD[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder, String]
```

I'm using Spark 1.3.0.
Does anyone has an idea about how to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you not using sc directly there without the asInstanceOf

Comment: Because seems that the compiler is not able to distinguish between the signature of the method that works with JavaSparkContext and the one with the SparkContext. However without the asIstanceOf the error was the same.

Comment: Can you paste the link of the full stack Trace from gist That would be helpful !

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by using the right type for the parameter leaderForPartitionsMap that must be Map[TopicAndPartition, org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.Broker]